How can I extend the method ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter#extraData
I want to modify the printed stack trace information based on this method, but I don't know how to proceed.
ch.qos.logback.classic.layout.TTLLLayout


The code here is fixed and cannot use SPI or other solutions
How can I extend the method ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter#extraData
I would like to add a trace ID before the exception stack
